# Nginx doesn't recognize subfolders

Tags: rest, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app on a VPS with nginx and gunicorn.

```
    location /app {
        root /var/www/mydomain.com/html/flask_app;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_redirect http://$http_host/ https://$http_host/;

        proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
    }
```

Mi Flask app has a route like this:

```
@app.route('/streaming_events', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/api/streaming_events', methods=['GET'])
def streaming_events():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        streaming_events = api.get_streaming_events()
        if request.path == '/api/streaming_events':
            response = jsonify(streaming_events)
            response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            return response

        return render_template('index.html', streaming_events=streaming_events)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        api.create_streaming_event(request.get_json())

    return jsonify({})
```

mydomain.com/app/streaming_events Works fine, but
mydomain.com/app/api/streaming_events gives me "Not Found".
It does work fine on my local machine.

Comment: did you run flask in prefix route ?

Comment: Try using: `location /app/` with a trailing `/`.

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried that, didn't work.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan yes, and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/fag2q5/flask_route_subdirectories/

Multiple segments of an URL are not allowed(by gunicorn/Flask?), it seems.
So the way to solve is this:

```
@app.route('/streaming_events', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/api/<path:path>', methods=['GET'])
def streaming_events(path=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        streaming_events = api.get_streaming_events()
        if request.path == '/api/streaming_events':
            response = jsonify(streaming_events)
            response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            return response

        return render_template('index.html', streaming_events=streaming_events)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        api.create_streaming_event(request.get_json())

    return jsonify({})
```